# Can I plant any fruit in my town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I know I can plant fruit I get from visiting other towns, such as apples or peaches or oranges, but if I plant the coconuts and the durian from the island, will they grow in my town? Or will those trees only grow on the island?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All growable fruits can be planted in all towns. There are the following restrictions:

- Palm trees only grow on sand, i.e. your beach. Palm trees are Coconut and Banana trees. These are easy to identify by the unique shape and the fact that they produce two fruits at a time, not three.

  - This includes Bananas and Coconuts
- Deciduous trees (including island fruit!) only grow in dirt, so not on your beach. These are all trees that have 3 fruits per tree, including the island fruit. Even on the island, deciduous trees won't grow in sand (a common mistake).

  - This includes pears, oranges, cherries, peaches, apples, durians, lyches, lemons, 
    mangos and persimmons
- **You cannot plant Perfect Fruit trees for non-native fruit**. Non-native perfect fruits will grow into regular trees of that fruit. Native perfect fruits will grow into trees that grow more perfect fruit before eventually (randomly) dying.

  - This means to get the most out of perfect fruit (3,000 bells per) you will need to grow lots of native perfect fruit and bring it to a town where it is not native for selling.