# Is my perfect fruit only perfect to me?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/how-do-perfect-fruits-work) we know that only the perfect native fruit to the town will grow into perfect trees.

If I share pears as the native with a friend's town, will her perfect pears sprout into perfect trees in my town, or will only perfect pears grown in my town grow into perfect trees?

Comment: This is also answered in my answer on [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121969/can-i-plant-any-fruit-in-my-town/121973#121973)

Comment: Not really, in the sense that it's not explicitly mentioned that a perfect fruit from someone else is guaranteed to grow (which is what I would like confirmed/denied)?

Comment: @Gwen but it *is* confirmed. Or would you like me to come to your town and plant a perfect tree just to prove it? :)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: That's linked in his opening sentence.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I am aware.  I think this falls in its scope.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I think that question could cover it but it doesn't at this point in time which is why I ended up asking my question?

Comment: @Gwen When an answer is not satisfactory, you should ask for more detail instead of asking a new question about the same thing.

Comment: I don't see this question answered within the text of the other question.

Comment: @CyberSkull That doesn't mean the _questions_ aren't the same.  The answer needs to be expanded.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot This is narrower in scope. Also given that the text of the other one doesn't address the issue it seems to me it is best served being left open.

Comment: @CyberSkull This being narrower is exactly why it should be closed.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I'm afraid I don't understand why that is a bad thing. The broad answer didn't address this issue at the time of this question's posting, so it seems to me at the time the issue was raised that this question was legit.

Comment: @CyberSkull Just because an answer doesn't address something that's part if its scope doesn't mean you should ask a new question about it.  You should ask for clarification on the existing answer or possibly offer a bounty.  That is how the site works.  We can continue this in [chat] if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfect trees will only grow from perfect fruit in the town that they are native. If you give someone a bunch of perfect fruit from your town and *they don't have that fruit natively*, planting them will yield regular trees.

To get anything else to yield a perfect tree, you need to use [Fertilizer](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Fertilizer) on a sapling, but this hasn't been tested with non-native fruit anywhere I've seen.

In short, if the perfect fruit is a fruit native to the town, planting it will always grow a perfect tree. The game does not (and cannot) differentiate between a bunch of fruit. Otherwise you couldn't stack them. Anything that is unique to you (such as a signature sheet) isn't something you can drop, anyway.

Comment: Your first paragraph kind of contradicts your conclusion?

Comment: @Gwen they only grow directly from perfect fruit that are planted (any perfect fruit that is non-native when planted will not be perfect)

Answer (score 2):

On [this page](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/perfect-fruit-guide/), which was also posted on the answer you've quoted, it is also stated that perfect trees will grow for native fruits, regardless of their origin.

In your case, if you were to share one of your perfect (native) pears with a friend that has native pears and he'd plant it, he'll get a perfect tree. 
Vice versa seems to be true as well, which means that a perfect native pear that your friend has grown in his city can be planted in your city with native pears to get a perfect pear tree.

Comment: It does not say "regardless of their origin" on that page, which is why it's not clear to me. I would like a hard statement either from a guide or anecdotal evidence or something?